# Going back to a previous buffer in emacs

Tags: emacs

I used `C-x u` and the screen I was typing on disappeared, so I tried creating again on the second question but it says that file already exists; how do go back to the one I created in the first question?

Comment: I don't understand.  Which "questions" are you referring to?  It's not at all clear what you've done.

Comment: That said... Use `C-x C-f` to visit an existing file.

Comment: Perhaps you have translated "shell prompt" as "question".  In that case I would think that you have started two separate instances of Emacs.  If you have actually killed that first shell, then that instance of Emacs is probably gone.  If the original shell is still present and Emacs was only suspended, then try the shell command `jobs` in the original shell to list any suspended jobs, and `fg` would put the most recent such job (if any) into the foreground.

Comment: Maybe ask on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5):

There's a suite of options based on what you're trying to accomplish:

1. `Ctrl-x <left>` jumps to your previous buffer, can be repeated to keep popping stack frames
2. `Ctrl-x b` opens a prompt in the minibuffer. The default option is the prior buffer, but you can use `<up>`/`<down>` keys to browse the prior stack of buffers
3. `Ctrl-x Ctrl-b` opens `*Buffer List*` where you can see all buffers and select the one you want

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go back to the previous buffer, probably you could use `Ctrl-X <left>` keybinding. If you want to go back to a previous window, you could try `Ctrl-C <left>` with `winner-undo`.

Edit:
To use `Ctrl-C <left>`, you should enable `winner-mode` first:

```
;;;Winner mode is an Emacs built-in package that lets you undo and redo window
;;;configurations. Incredibly useful since I keep splitting and merging windows
;;;https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode
(when (fboundp 'winner-mode)
  (winner-mode t))
```

Comment: Ctrl-C <left> does not work on GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.36, cairo version 1.17.6) of 2023-01-03. Returns this message: "C-c <left> is undefined".

Comment: Probably, you have to enable the `winner-mode` first, with this statement `(when (fboundp 'winner-mode)
  (winner-mode t))`